# com excel addin: how to uninstall older version when install newer version after product name change

Tags: c#, excel, com, installation, add-in

Env: Visual Studio 2008, Shared COM Excel Addin, RibbonX,  I use Setup project created in VS 2008

.NET framework 35 SP1

product name changes say: prod name is myProd for version 1.0, prod name is myProdX for version 1.1

1. When I install version 1.1, I want to uninstall 1.0 first
2. user setting is saved in a folder A in 1.0, it will be saved to a different folder B in 1.1. I want move the file from 1.0 to 1.1

We do not want to manually do 1 or 2.

Is it possible to achieve the two automatically either in installer or somewhere and how?

thanks for any idea, advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After search & experiment, here's how I solved the issue, maybe not the best way
1. keep the same upgradecode in setup project, set removePreviousVersions to true
2. in custom Action,  in public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
I added code to move files from old folder to new folder